# Module not found after setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have a setup.py file below and I

```
maindir
   |- setup.py
   |-src
         |- __init__.py
         |- pipeline.py
         |- parameter.py
```

and

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License (GPL)'
    ],  
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['step1 = src.pipeline:step1']}
)
```

where `pipeline.py` has `import parameter` at the top.

I ran `python setup.py install` but afterwards it said it couldn't find the module `parameter.py`. So then instead of using `packages = find_packages()` I used `packages=['src/parameter','src']` but then I have to change `import parameter` to `import src.parameter`. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any packages under `src` so `find_packages()` doesn't find any. Listing `'src/parameter'` as a package is meaningless as it's not a package (a directory with file `__init__.py`), it's a module. Only `'src'` is a package here.

> I have to change `import parameter` to `import src.parameter`

Python 3, I suppose? Python 3 prefers absolute import but allows relative import. So either use `import src.parameter` or `import .parameter`

`import parameter` is an absolute import in Python 3 (in Python 2 it was relative+absolute import), i.e. Python searches through `sys.path` to find `parameter` and fails.